# Connection pool abstract class

Tags: java, database, connection-pooling

I am implementing an abstract class for connection pools. The goal is inherit this class to manage a connection pool for each database used in the program and encapsulate the common queries. I have serveral doubts:

1. Is efficient to get a connection from the pool and close it after do the query or is better implement it in another level to keep open the connection? (method selecSimple). I did a test with 100000 queries:

   - Took 86440 milliseconds getting and closing a connection from the pool for each query.
   - And 81107 milliseconds getting only one connection from the pool and using it to do all the queries, so I think there is not such a big difference.
2. I pass the ResultSet data to another container to release the connection as soon as posible, even if I have to go over the data twice, one to put the data into the new container and another later when it will be used. Do you think, it is a good practice or should be better to implement the queries in another level?

```java
public abstract class ConnectionPool implements IConnectionPool {
/**  Connection Pool dataSource */
private DataSource datasource;

@Override
public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    return datasource.getConnection();
}

@Override
public void closeConnectionPool() {
    datasource.close();
}

@Override
public void setConnectionPool (String url, String driver, String user, String pass) throws SQLException {
    // Using tomcat connection pool but it could be other
    PoolProperties pool = new PoolProperties();
    pool.setUrl(url);
    // Set pool configuration
    ...    
    datasource = new DataSource();
    datasource.setPoolProperties(pool);
}

// QUERIES  
@Override
public List<Map<String, Object>> selectSimple (String query, String [] params) throws SQLException {        
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    Connection con = null;
    List<Map<String, Object>> results = null;
    // Set the preparedstatement
    ...     
    try {
        con = getConnection();
        ps = con.prepareStatement(selectString);
        rs = ps.executeQuery(selectString);
        results = resultSetToArrayList(rs);

        rs.close();
        ps.close();
        con.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new SQLException ();
    } finally {
        if (rs != null) rs.close();
        if (ps != null) ps.close();
        if (con != null) ps.close();
    }
    return results;
}

/** Transforms ResultSet into a List of Maps */
private List<Map<String, Object>> resultSetToArrayList(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
    ...
    return list;
}
```

So, When the app finishes, will be enough closing the datasource to release the resources?(closeConnectionPool method).
I would greatly appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your servlet container is managing the `ConnectionPool`, I'm not sure how useful this will be.  And in most cases, the servlet container will be better at it than you are.

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that is for a desktop app, not a webbapp. The main question, is how to release the connection pool resources when it finishes the database process. And then if you find useful this class. Thanks.